# Now() function is getting populated with different date time other than excepted in postgresql 9.6.9

Tags: postgresql

We are having some columns in database with data type 'timestamp with time zone'. We are populating with now() function as default value. Sometimes it is getting populated with dates from 2017/18. What might be the issue?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Are you sure the problem isn't in the underlying OS? `now()` and `current_timestamp` rely on the OS to get their values. Btw, consider updating your database version.. 9.6 is a solid version but already very old.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `now()` as default value, the likely cause of your problem is that these dates are inserted explicitly. Remember that the default value is only used if no value is supplied for the column.

There are other, much less likely explanations like database transactions that have been open for a year, but I don't believe that.

If you *always* want to override the value, use a `BEFORE` trigger.